# Cant find "project individual elements"

Tags: workflow

**I tried everything but the "project individual elements" command still doesn't appear.[image]**

Comment: Hi. From the User Interface section of this page: https://developer.blender.org/docs/release_notes/4.0/modeling/

"Project Individual Elements has been replaced with the Face Project option"